# Access history of a file

Tags: files, monitoring, stat

I was wondering if there are any tools to keep track of the access history of a file. I know of [stat](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/stat.1.html), but as far as I understand, it only returns information about the last time the file was accessed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logging access times is already a fairly heavy requirement (by filesystem performance standards), because it requires a write operation for every read operation. Logging other things would be even costlier. The feature is not present in typical filesystems.

[LoggedFS](http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/) is a stackable filesystem that provides a view of a filesystem tree, and can perform fancier logging of all accesses through that view. To configure it, see [LoggedFS configuration file syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13794/loggedfs-configuration-file-syntax).

On Linux, you can use the [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/) to log a large number of things, including filesystem accesses. Make sure the `auditd` daemon is started, then configure what you want to log with [`auditctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/auditctl.8.html). Each logged operation is recorded in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` (on typical distributions). To start watching a particular file:

```
auditctl -w /path/to/file
```

If you put a watch on a directory, the files in it and its subdirectories recursively are also watched.

Answer (score 0):

This information is not stored in the classic filesystems, like ext2/3/4, vfat etc etc. So if you need file history you either need to use a filesystem that has this or put the file in a revision system like svn or git.

Comment: Are there such filesystems?

Comment: git, hg or SVN do not keep track of file access unless you retrieve the file through their interface. I am looking for something that would work for regular file access. Thanks though.