# Get all accessed dates from a file

Tags: files, date

I know that in file's properties It is displayed the last time a file was accessed, but does anybody know If It is possible in Linux to get all the dates for a file that has been accessed (opened) and not just the last time?

If not, is there any 3rd-party application that can do this job?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered in @Gilles previous post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18684/access-history-of-a-file#18689).

Bottom line is that the `auditd` subsystem should be available in your repository.

[Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=auditd) has a considerable number of posts that should help you with the setup.

A simple starters guide for auditd is [over here](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-monitor-file-access-on-linux.html)