# How to list all the processes which have accessed a particular file?

Tags: lsof, strace

`strace` can monitor only one single processes not all, `lsof` is not a good way too, it's not a real time tool, maybe I need a real time version of `lsof`? How to list all the processes which have accessed a particular file?

Comment: I think you're looking for either `auditd` (not for the faint-hearted) or `inotify`.

Comment: You can relate to this : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18684/access-history-of-a-file

Comment: Issue following in command prompt respectively      auditctl -w /path/to/afil.txt      tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log When I open afil.txt, /var/log/audit/audit.log has no change, audit.log get refreshed if I move afil.txt to Trash, but not the huge number of things as they said, is that any mistake in my issue?

Comment: Issue following in command prompt respectively    auditctl -w /path/to/afil.txt    tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log  When I open afil.txt, /var/log/audit/audit.log has no change, audit.log get refreshed if I move afil.txt to Trash, but not the huge number of things as they said, is that any mistake in my issue?

Comment: very sorry for comment formatting

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`fanotify(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html). It's similar to inotify, but it tells you the PID of the accessing process.

Comment: I forget to tell you I have only one suspicious program running on my Linux needs to be monitored, will the program call other "normal" programs for the access?

Comment: Issue following in command prompt respectively
    auditctl -w /path/to/afil.txt
    tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log
When I open afil.txt, /var/log/audit/audit.log has no change, audit.log get refreshed if I move afil.txt to Trash, but not the huge number of things as they said, is that any mistake in my issue?