# List the files accessed by a program

Tags: files, monitoring, strace

`time` is a brilliant command if you want to figure out how much CPU time a given command takes.

I am looking for something similar that can list the files being accessed by a program and its children. Either in real time or as a report afterwards.

Currently I use:

```
#!/bin/bash

strace -ff -e trace=file "$@" 2>&1 | perl -ne 's/^[^"]+"(([^\\"]|\\[\\"nt])*)".*/$1/ && print'
```

but its fails if the command to run involves `sudo`. It is not very intelligent (it would be nice if it could only list files existing or that had permission problems or group them into files that are read and files that are written). Also `strace` is slow, so it would be good with a faster choice.

Comment: Given your use of `strace`, I assume you're specifically interested in Linux. Correct?

Comment: Linux is my primary concern.

Comment: Interesting side effect: when running this code with $@ equal to "firefox", when I'm already running firefox, a new firefox process spawns.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I gave up and coded my own tool. To quote from its docs:

```
SYNOPSIS
    tracefile [-adefnu] command
    tracefile [-adefnu] -p pid

OPTIONS
    -a        List all files
    -d        List only dirs
    -e        List only existing files
    -f        List only files
    -n        List only non-existing files
    -p pid    Trace process id
    -u        List only files once
```

It only outputs the files so you do not need to deal with the output from `strace`.

https://codeberg.org/tange/tangetools/src/branch/master/tracefile

Comment: thanks! strace's output is absolutely unreadable. I don't know where to find the docs though - it would be nice if it had a -h/--help option. I'd also appreciate an option that only shows file edits, not accesses.

Comment: @Xerus Clone https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools and run `make && sudo make install`. Then you can run `man tracefile`.

Comment: Nice tool. Packaged it, to install: `yum -y install https://extras.getpagespeed.com/release-el7-latest.rpm` and `yum -y install tracefile`

Answer (score 32):

You can trace the system calls with `strace`, but there is indeed an inevitable speed penalty. You need to run `strace` as root if the command runs with elevated privileges:

```
sudo strace -f -o foo.trace su user -c 'mycommand'
```

Another method that's likely to be faster is to preload a library that wraps around filesystem access functions: `LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libmywrapper.so mycommand`. The `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable won't be passed to programs invoked with elevated privileges. You'd have to write the code of that wrapper library ([here's an example from “Building library interposers for fun and profit”](http://www.drdobbs.com/building-library-interposers-for-fun-and/184404926)); I don't know if there is reusable code available on the web.

If you're monitoring the files in a particular directory hierarchy, you can make a view of the filesystem with [LoggedFS](https://rflament.github.io/loggedfs/) such that all accesses through that view are logged.

```
loggedfs -c my-loggedfs.xml /logged-view
mycommand /logged-view/somedir
```

To configure LoggedFS, start with the sample configuration shipped with the program and read [LoggedFS configuration file syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13794/loggedfs-configuration-file-syntax).

Another possibility is Linux's [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/). Make sure the `auditd` daemon is started, then configure what you want to log with [`auditctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/auditctl.8.html). Each logged operation is recorded in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` (on typical distributions). To start watching a particular file:

```
auditctl -a exit,always -w /path/to/file
```

If you put a watch on a directory, the files in it and its subdirectories recursively are also watched. Take care not to watch the directory containing the audit logs. You can restrict the logging to certain processes, see the `auditctl` man page for the available filters. You need to be root to use the audit system.

Comment: `LD_PRELOAD` also won't work on static binaries.

Answer (score 12):

I think you want lsof (possibly piped to a grep on the program and it's children).  It will tell you every file that's currently being accessed on the filesystem.  For information about which files accessed by process ([from here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92013/monitoring-file-changes-process-access-to-files)):

```
lsof -n -p `pidof your_app`
```

Comment: But it only gives me a snapshot. What I need is what files it tried to access. Think of the situation where a program refuses to start because it says "Missing file". How do I figure out what file it was looking for?

Answer (score 4):

I tried that `tracefile`. For me it gave much less matches than my own `strace ... | sed ... | sort -u`. I even added `-s256` to `strace(1)` command line but it did not help much...

Then I tried that `loggedfs`. First it failed since I did not have read/write access to the directory I tried to log with it. After doing *chmod 755* temporarily I did get some hits...

But, for me, doing the following seems to work best:

`inotifywait -m -r -e OPEN /path/to/traced/directory`

And then postprocess the output after running the process of interest.

This doesn't catch the files process access outsice of the
*traced directory* nor this doesn't know whether some other
process accessed the same directory tree, but in many cases
this is good enough tool to get the job done.

EDIT: inotifywait does not catch symlink access (just the targets
after symlinks resolved). I was hit by this when I archived libraries
accessed by a program for future use. Used some extra perl glob hackery
to pick the symlinks along the notified libraries to get the job
done in that one particular case.

EDIT2: at least when inotifying files and symlinks themselves from inotifywait command line (e.g. `inotifywait -m file symlink` or `inotifywait symlink file`) output will show access to which one is first in command line (regardless which, `file` of `symlink` is accessed). inotifywait does not support IN_DONT_FOLLOW -- which, when
I tried programmatically just makes one see access to `file` (which may,
or may not, be what one expects...) regardless of order in command line

Comment: "For me it gave much less matches than my own" Can you share an example of `tracefile` missing a file access?

Comment: I am not sure what you'te exactly asking :)... If I try to look files inside /path/to/traced/directory/ I see OPEN in inotify output... BUT stat(1) ing the files I seem to get no results in the few cases I tried (I wonder why, is some caching hiding directory content reading from view)

Comment: I'm commenting the fanotify post below (I have only 21 reputation, although I've had account for more than a decade; requiring 50 for commenting has  always been obstacle for me...) -- fanotify is good stuff, but cannot go around the symlink dereference issue (i.e. in case of symlinks, the final file accessed is found by reading /proc/self/fd/<fd> .. anyway +1:ing the answer :D

Answer (score 2):

While it might not give you enough control (yet?) I have written a program, which at least partially fulfills your needs,
using the linux-kernel's fanotify and unshare to monitor only files modified (or read) by a specific process and its children.
Compared to strace, it is quite fast (;

It can be found on
https://github.com/tycho-kirchner/shournal

Example on the shell:

```
$ shournal -e sh -c 'echo hi > foo1; echo hi2 > foo2'
$ shournal -q --history 1
  # ...
  Written file(s):                                                                                                                                                                              
 /tmp/foo1 (3 bytes) Hash: 15349503233279147316                                                                                                                                             
 /tmp/foo2 (4 bytes) Hash: 2770363686119514911
```

Answer (score 2):

For my needs this is sufficient:

```
strace [program] 2>&1 | grep 'openat'
```

For example:

```
$ strace sensors 2>&1 | grep 'openat'
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3                 
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsensors.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3  
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3  
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3   
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class/i2c-adapter", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-3/name", O_RDONLY) = 4  
...
```

Not really sure why everyone is over-complicating this

Comment: To color only the filenames: `strace subl 2>&1 | grep 'openat' | grep -e '".*"' --color=auto`

Answer (score 1):

strace -f -e open [command] 2>&1

Comment: "Also strace is slow, so it would be good with a faster choice"