# Is there any tool that shows live changes to all files in the log folder?

Tags: logs, utilities

I am currently debugging a weird problem on my server and therefore I am searching for a tool that is monitoring the standard log folder `/var/log/`. Any changes to the existing files should be printed so that I know what exactly happens.

As I am not just starting one program but rather making requests to different services strace is not helping. Solutions proposed here [monitoring file changes + process access to files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92013/monitoring-file-changes-process-access-to-files) are outdated or limited to non-recursive folder structures.

Comment: Tried `inotifywait` with `-r`?

Comment: Nope not yet. Will try it soon, does it work on any folder depth?

Comment: Okay, so thanks for the input, this is working fine for detecting any changes at all - what I'm searching for is for a tool to print the modified lines directly.

Comment: Log files are modifying in a very specific way, only by appending lines. The tool of choice is `tail -F`, or, if you don't want to write your own multiple-tail script, [`multitail`](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/); check whether it's available as an installable package or else download it from the author's site.

Comment: Cool, this pretty much what I wanted. What I now tried to is to make it use all files in the log folder, like this:
`multitail -c --mergeall "$(find . -type f | grep -v gz | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g')"`
Sadly there is still one small error remaining (the parsing of the whitespaces) but I hope I can fix it soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [multitail](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) to watch content that gets added to multiple files. It's like [`tail -f`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)#File_monitoring) on steroids. To watch files in a directory and its subdirectories, get your shell or `find` to list the files.

```
cd /var/log
multitail -n 0 --mergeall **/*.log
```

In bash, run `shopt -s globstar` first to activate `**` as a recursive directory glob. In ksh, run `set -o globstar`. In zsh, it's on by default.

Comment: Did not know that about using ** - thanks!  And yes, one more vote for tail -f or a variant thereof

Comment: That's really useful, thanks!
Any chance you can help me fix the find code I posted in the comment above? It allows a more granular filtering of the log files: 
`multitail -c --mergeall "$(find . -type f | grep -v gz | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g')"`

Comment: @matt3o `shopt -s extglob` then `multitail … **/!(*.gz)`