# How can I list a file all modified time?

Tags: linux

Use the `stat file` I can check the file's recent modify time, and create time.

```
[root@controller network-scripts]# stat ifcfg-enp2s0f0
  文件："ifcfg-enp2s0f0"
  大小：444        块：8          IO 块：4096   普通文件
device：fd00h/64768d Inode：1708165     硬链接：1
limit：(0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid：(    0/    root)   Gid：(    0/    root)
recent access：2017-10-08 19:51:13.715800341 +0800
最近更改：2017-08-31 14:57:14.703346036 +0800
recent change：2017-08-31 14:57:14.745346036 +0800
创建时间：-
```

Whether there is a method to list all the time that changed the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normal file system does not store a change log.

How to monitor file system changes is answered here:

- [monitoring file changes + process access to files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92013/monitoring-file-changes-process-access-to-files)

Comment: and the xxx/network-script/ifcfg-enp2s0f0 do not store the change log too?

Answer (score 0):

No filesystem that I know of stores every modification time. Most give you only what you have already presented: creation, last access, and last modification.

---

As an experiment, make a tiny partition, maybe 32M or so. Put your preferred filesystem on it, and mount this partition somewhere (I'll use `/mnt` for this example). Some of the available size will be taken up by filesystem data, but we can ignore that. Time is stored as a 32- or 64-bit number of seconds since some epoch; we'll assume 32 here.

32M is 33554432 bytes. 32 bits is 4 bytes, so you could store 8,388,608 timestamps on a completely empty partition. Run a loop:

```
for ((x=0; x < 8500000; x=x+1)); do
    touch /mnt/somefile
done
```

This will `touch` a file on the filesystem 8.5 million times (and probably take a while). Importantly, if your system is storing every timestamp, then at some point you'll get a message that the filesystem is full.