# Generic debugging / logging / tracing filesystem directory & file access?

Tags: filesystems, debugging, access-control

This is my particular problem: I'm trying to set up `git` on a server, for which I'm doing a test on a locally installed `apache` on Ubuntu 14.04; for instance, I can do `git clone` fine over HTTP, but  `git push` fails with `insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects`.

Now, in principle, I might have used `strace` for debugging this, but this kind of action goes through both `git` and `apache`, and as such I don't really know which process to `strace`. Furthermore, I cannot even tell what user does the end operation try to run as. The only thing that I know for sure is that it is the git repo `./objects` directory which is being accessed, probably with the intent of creating a file there.

So I thought, probably the easiest for me would be if there was a program, that could be set to "listen" to accesses to a directory, and print out/log every such access to say stdout; in example as in this pseudocode:

```
$ ./traceDirectoryAccess --path /path/to/mygitrepo/objects
Listening for accesses on /path/to/mygitrepo/objects ...
Sat Apr  9 17:53:42 CEST 2016 - pid 1234, user myName (uid 1002) did:
 > create file /path/to/mygitrepo/objects/somefile
 > result: permission DENIED
...
```

Is there something like this out there? If there isn't a program per se, maybe there is some kernel facility (e.g. through a file in `/sys/kernel/debug/` or similar?)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found an answer on this very site: [List the files accessed by a program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/list-the-files-accessed-by-a-program/18872#18872) explains that one can use [LoggedFS](http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/) or the Linux [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/).