# How do I trace why printing pdf from Ghostscript vs Evince is different?

Tags: pdf, printing, ghostscript

I'm trying to get a better sense of how the "Print to File" option works on Linux Mint. Basically, when I open a PDF with Evince and print it to PDF, the output is different from the original, and typically quirks in the original file are cleaned up in the output. If I pipe the original file through Ghostscript instead, the output is closer to the original. How do I figure out how "Print to File" works differently from Ghostscript?

Comment: Strace would be one way -- http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18872/117549

Comment: I played around with `strace` for a while but it looks like that shows low level system calls. I'm more interested in the various applications/processes that get triggered by a particular process. I've still got some to learn about it, though. Is there a way to get this information using `strace`?

Comment: Look for exec calls. Also, -f follow children processes.

Comment: Hmm, no `exec` calls in the output. I tacked on a `-f`, too. A lot of `read`, `write` and random other system calls.

Comment: It may be that they are standalone, independent processes (and code bases) that simply do it differently.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's probably true, but I'm trying to get a better idea of what those look like. Ghostscript is easy enough to come by, but how would I go about finding the printer stuff?

Comment: I'm out of my depth, but if I were you I'd probably dig into the [source for evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/Downloads). Also, consider editing your Q's title to reflect your actual goal (pdf differences) to avoid red herring chases (like strace)