# Filter out failed syscalls from strace log

Tags: system-calls, strace

I can run `strace` on a command like `sleep 1`
and see what files it's accessing like this:

```
strace -e trace=file -o strace.log sleep 1
```

However, on my machine, many of the calls have a return value of -1
indicating that the file does not exist. For example:

```
$ grep '= -1 ENOENT' strace.log | head
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MEASUREMENT", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_TELEPHONE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_ADDRESS", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_NAME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_PAPER", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I'm not really interested in the files that don't exist,
I want to know what files the process actually found and read from.
Aside from `grep -v '=-1 ENOENT'`,
how can I reliably filter out failed calls?

## Addendum

I was surprised to learn
that `strace` has had this feature in the works since 2002
in the form of the `-z` flag, which is an alias for `-e status=successful`,
fully functional [since version 5.2](https://github.com/strace/strace/commit/e45a594cb08394c96f71105db9bacf08aa4c734d)
([2019-07-12](https://github.com/strace/strace/releases/tag/v5.2)),
also available as `--successful-only` [since version 5.6](https://github.com/strace/strace/commit/092724f8041cdfb64dcaf68a2d8ba877b509ea83) ([2020-04-07](https://github.com/strace/strace/releases/tag/v5.6)).

Also available since version 5.2 is the complement of `-z`, the `-Z` flag,
which is an alias for `-e status=failed`,
available as `--failed-only` since version 5.6.

The `-z` flag was [first added in a commit from 2002](https://github.com/strace/strace/commit/17f8fb3484e94976882f65b7a3aaffc6f24cd75d) and released in version 4.5.18 ([2008-08-28](https://github.com/strace/strace/releases/tag/v4.5.18)),
bit it had never been [documented](https://github.com/strace/strace/commit/de6e53308ca58da7d357f8114afc74fff7a18043) because it was not working properly.

Relevant links:

- only seeing successful system calls

  Sat Nov 2 23:07:23 UTC 2002

  > When using strace I  sometimes like to see the system calls
  >   which work (instead of all the system calls).
  >
  > I've been porting this patch for years, it seems very useful.
  >
  > With the -z option, you don't see opens on files which aren't there
  >   (very useful tracking down what a program actually does, instead of
  >   trying to do).

  https://lists.strace.io/pipermail/strace-devel/2002-November/000232.html
- strace: -z option doesn't work properly

  Date: Sun, 12 Jan 2003 09:33:01 UTC

  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=176376
- tracing only failing syscalls

  Created: 2004-03-19

  https://sourceforge.net/p/strace/feature-requests/3/
- [strace-4.15] Proposal: Output Staging for -z Option (print successful syscalls only) / Patch included

  Tue Jan 17 09:35:54 UTC 2017

  https://lists.strace.io/pipermail/strace-devel/2017-January/005941.html
- [PATCH v1] Implemented output staging for failed/successful syscalls

  Wed Jan 18 16:01:20 UTC 2017

  https://lists.strace.io/pipermail/strace-devel/2017-January/005950.html
- Fix -z option

  Feb 28, 2018

  https://github.com/strace/strace/issues/49
- [PATCH 0/3] Stage output for -z and new -Z options

  Mon Apr 1 21:13:02 UTC 2019

  https://lists.strace.io/pipermail/strace-devel/2019-April/008706.html
- strace -z flag

  Mon Jun 10 05:29:19 UTC 2019

  https://lists.strace.io/pipermail/strace-devel/2019-June/008808.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from post-processing the `strace` output, there isn’t anything available to ignore failed system calls in `strace`. It wouldn’t be too hard to add, look at the `syscall_exiting_trace` function in [`syscall.c`](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/master/syscall.c).

If you’d rather pursue the post-processing angle, [Ole Tange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2972/ole-tange) has already taken care of that for you in a more comprehensive way than you’re likely to get here: the [`tracefile`](https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/tree/master/tracefile) tool will run `strace` and filter out the information you’re after in a nicely readable fashion. See [List the files accessed by a program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18844/86440) for details. [Another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18872/86440) to that question lists other possible approaches, including [LoggedFS](https://rflament.github.io/loggedfs/) which I find very useful.

Another option is to use [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/documentation.html); for example

```
#!/usr/bin/env stap

global stored_filename, stored_path

probe syscall.open {
  stored_filename = filename
}

probe syscall.open.return {
  if (execname() == "cat" && $return >= 0) {
    printf("opened %s\n", stored_filename)
  }
}

probe syscall.openat {
  stored_filename = filename
  stored_path = dfd_str
}

probe syscall.openat.return {
  if (execname() == "cat" && $return >= 0) {
    printf("opened %s in %s\n", stored_filename, stored_path)
  }
}
```

will show the name of any file successfully opened by any `cat` process.

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution:

```
strace -e trace=file sleep 1 2>&1 | grep -v "= -1 ENOENT" > strace.log
```

`strace` by default prints to `stderr` so redirect it to `stdout`.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more reliable pattern (i.e. slightly less risk of skipping the wrong lines by accident) could be

```
| grep -v "= -1 ENOENT [(]No such file or directory[)]$"
```

I.e. copy-paste the end of line, "escaping" the brackets (which might otherwise be treated as special characters), and add the special character `$` to the end which "anchors" the pattern to the end of the line.

I can't find any better option in `man strace`.  Quick and dirty text manipulation hacks are the Unix Way :-P.

It's almost certainly possible to do what you want with a custom `gdb` script.  However that's more work, and I don't have such a script prepared.

Another question references a `tracefile` script, which you would run with the `-e` option.  This is still implemented by parsing the output of `strace`, and so it does not appear to be entirely reliable either, but I guess it's possible you'd prefer it.  https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/blob/master/tracefile/tracefile