# Is it possible to monitor all write access to the filesystem of all process

Tags: filesystems, logs, monitoring

Is it possible to monitor all write access to the filesystem of all process under linux?

I've some different mounted filesystems. A lot of them are `tempfs`.

I'm interested in all writes to the root filesystem except the `tempfs, devtmpfs` etc.

I'm looking for something that will output: `<PID xy> write n Bytes to /targe/filepath ...`.
What monitoring tool can list all this write syscalls? Can they be filtered by mount points?

Comment: you most likely won't be able to do this. To monitor IO to fs, you can use inotify but it will not indicate the amount of read write byte nor the PID, only the file that has been read/write. You can use lsof to list open file by any process with it's process ID but it's instantanious not monitored so you could miss some short file IO. finally you can attach strace to a program, but it's CPU intensive and I'm not sure a system coulc attached strace to all the process. `strace` is the most complete solution but it is the more complexe as well and probably can't be use system wide.

Comment: inotify would be nice, but limit reached by `inotifywait -mr /`

Comment: @Kiwy why limit yourself to user-space tools? ;-)

Comment: @StephenKitt I already told you I'm a POWER user I tend to stay in the userspace :D

Comment: *What monitoring tool can list all this write syscalls?*  [Auditing.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/chap-system_auditing)

Comment: Please don't cross post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946478

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of tools you can use in various scenarios depending on the exact information you’re looking for. [Brendan Gregg](http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html) has a nice summary:

[image: Diagram of observability tools]

For I/O to specific devices, `blktrace` [might be appropriate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274163/86440), although it can be difficult to map its output to specific files.

A better tool for your case could be [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/documentation.html); it’s definitely worth taking the time to learn how to use it. You’d have to trace all file opens and writes, and then post-process the output. That will still miss I/O from memory-mapped files; you’d be able to see that with `blktrace` but that would be post-pagecache so it wouldn’t catch every explicit write (there’s a discussion of that somewhere on this site but I can’t find it just now). See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447063/86440) for an example involving SystemTap (to trace opened files).

Comment: `auditd` comes to mind here.

Comment: It does indeed @Stéphane, but I’ve never used it... [The Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/chap-system_auditing) seems like a nice introduction.