# -bash: /dev/null: Permission denied

Tags: permissions

I'm trying to create a new user on a Centos 6 system.

First, I do

```
useradd kevin
```

Then, I tried to run commands as that user

```
su - kevin
```

However, I get the following error messages

```
-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
[kevin@gazelle ~]$
```

And I can't do very much as that user.

The permissions on `/dev/null` are as follows:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root           9 Jul 25 17:07 null
```

Roughly the same as they are on my Mac,

```
crw-rw-rw-   1 root   wheel         3,   2 Jul 25 14:08 null
```

It's *possible*, but really unlikely, that I touched dev.

As the root user, I tried adding `kevin` to the `root` group:

```
usermod -a -G root kevin
```

However I still am getting `/dev/null` permission denied errors.

Why can't the new user write to `/dev/null`?
What groups should the new user be a part of?
Am I not impersonating the user correctly?
Is there a beginners guide to setting up users/permissions on Linux?

Comment: Looks like /dev/null got changed to a 9-byte-long ordinary file; it's supposed to be a device file ('c' at the beginning of the file type/permission bits field). If you `cat /dev/null`, does it look like something you recently used?

Comment: ah. yes it did. "* master". do you want to add that as the answer & I'll mark it?

Comment: You can reboot and /dev/null will get remade, but do you know what happened to change /dev/null into a file? It'd be a pain if it happened again.

Comment: My guess is I moved the output of "git branch" to /dev/null instead of writing it, or had a bad script or something

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Someone evidently moved a regular file to /dev/null. Rebooting will recreate it, or do

```
rm -f /dev/null; mknod -m 666 /dev/null c 1 3
```

As @Flow has noted in a comment, you must be `root` to do this.

`1` and `3` here are the device major and minor number on Linux-based OSes (the 3rd device handled by the `mem` driver, see `/proc/devices`, `cat /sys/devices/virtual/mem/null/dev`, `readlink /sys/dev/char/1:3`). It varies with the OS. For instance, it's `2`, `2` [on OpenBSD](/a/190310) and [AIX](/a/597766), it may also not be always the same on a given OS. Some OSes may supply a `makedev` / `MAKEDEV` command to help recreate them.

Comment: If by "someone" you mean "me", then yes :)

Comment: Even i ran int the same issue on server. ubuntu 14.04 LTS. But I didn't change permissions. Is there any possiblity where I can track which process changed the permissions?

Comment: @Mani Linux by default doesn't log such small changes, but you can turn on auditing to see them from now on. [How to detect on Linux chmod of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391286/how-to-detect-on-linux-chmod-of-a-file)

Comment: The solution fixes the problem but the issue reoccurs. Why?

Comment: @AbhishekSoni You might try auditing, as described in [Display a file's history (list of users that have modified a file)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42234/display-a-files-history-list-of-users-that-have-modified-a-file)

Answer (score 21):

This should fix the issue (as root):

```
rm /dev/null
mknod /dev/null c 1 3
chmod 666 /dev/null
```

What these commands are doing:

- `rm`is removing the bogus file that has been created because the expected one was missing;
- `mknod` is creating a character device named `/dev/null` with the appropriate major and minor numbers for a Linux kernel;
- `chmod` is setting the permissions for all users to be able to read and write to `/dev/null`.

Comment: This one also works on Mac/BSD

Comment: this answer works but can yu explain those cmds? @jlliagre

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN Explanations added.

Answer (score 7):

The solution suggested by Mark did not work on OpenBSD.
However

```
mknod -m 666 /dev/null c 2 2
```

did the trick. I have tested this on OpenBSD 5.6. When the accepted answer is executed `/dev/null` will block and screw any code reading from it pretty badly.

To re-create all standard devices on OpenBSD (`null` included), you should use (as root):

```
cd /dev
./MAKEDEV std
```

Comment: Didn't the OP use CentOS rather than OpenBSD?

Comment: Unfortunately, different operating systems use different major/minor numbers for `/dev/null`, and there's no standard. OP asked about CentOS 6. Linux has used `1,3` for /dev/null going back to at least 2001. On FreeBSD, I've seen `0,6`,  `15,0`, `17,0`, and `20,0`. OpenBSD uses `2,2`. On OpenBSD, you actually don't need to know the numbers; you can run `# cd /dev; ./MAKEDEV std` .

Comment: Major and minor numbers are not transportable between operating systems.  What works on Linux won't usually work on *BSD or Mac OS X (or Solaris, AIX, HP-UX, …), and vice versa.  You have to find the correct numbers to  use in the `mknod` command by scrutiny of the manuals (if you're lucky, the information is in there) or by scrutiny of the kernel headers.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me on windows within the Ubuntu application, while trying to run a script that wrote into `/dev/null`. Permissions were correct for both `/dev` and `/dev/null`.

Turned out the problem was windows newlines in the script file. Running :

`dos2unix.exe c:\path\to\script.sh`

Solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the Mac OS X answer for posterity...

```
sudo sh -c '
  rm -rf /dev/null &&
    mknod /dev/null c 3 2 &&
    chmod 666 /dev/null'
```

Comment: @Kusalananda, I've corrected that. I can't comment on whether 3, 2 are the correct major/minor on macos or not.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `3 2` should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

For IBM AIX Server i did the same and it's working

```
# rm /dev/null;mknod /dev/null c 2 2;chown root:system /dev/null;chmod 0666 /dev/null

# ls -l /dev/null
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     system        2,  2 Jul 10 22:18 /dev/null
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank your for your contribution. Please note that your solution looks very much like the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146639/377345). You may want to edit it to make the difference more clear.

Comment: Yes, for AIX it is major=2, minor=2 not the same as it is in Linux.