# How to record filesystem operations history?

Tags: linux, files, logs

Is it possible to record recent files operation? By operations i mean moving, renaming, deleting, creating etc. Not full log with seeks and stuff.

Comment: @gilles:  I reread this question and the one you linked to along with its answers and I don't see them even remotely similar.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Ok, that was a slightly different variation on the theme of logging file accesses (one process vs unspecified). How about [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12247/linux-file-access-monitoring)? We've covered this topic many times.

Comment: @Gilles:  That is a **much** better choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `auditd`, as described in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd):

> `auditd` is the userspace component to the Linux Auditing System. It's responsible for writing audit records to the disk.

It can manage many different user operations which are defined in its [rules](https://linux.die.net/man/7/audit.rules).  In your case, you'd want to look at the `File System` section.