# How to see laptop camera logs on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, logs, camera

I would like to know if it is possible to discover when my laptop camera was used over the past 7 days. eg. Is there a log for that?

I am running on a Ubuntu 18 machine.

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/848245/laptop-web-camera-active-history

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know if my webcam is used or not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344454/how-to-know-if-my-webcam-is-used-or-not)

Comment: @K7AAY I don't see in which respect the second link is a duplicate. It's a different thing to know if the webcam is used this second or when during the past days.