# Why would `lsof /dev/video0` be insufficient to check what processes are using the camera?

Tags: camera, lsof

A [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344454/how-to-know-if-my-webcam-is-used-or-not) about this command from half a decade ago claims that `lsof` does not monitor all the processes using cam.  But when I ran the command while running testcam I got:

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox-b 3077  lax  mem    CHR   81,0           808 /dev/video0
firefox-b 3077  lax  143u   CHR   81,0      0t0  808 /dev/video0
```

What does the `DEVICE` `81,0` indicate. I can't quite understand how it's not being monitored since its displaying blocks 81,0.

Answer (score 18):

`lsof /dev/video0` only lists processes that have `/dev/video0` open. Suppose that the administrator runs this command:

```
mknod /somewhere/else c 81 0
```

Then a program can use the camera device through the device file `/somewhere/else`. This access won't be visible with `lsof /dev/video0`, but will be visible with `lsof /somewhere/else`.

Only root can create device nodes. On a normal system, `/dev/video0` is the only device file for the webcam. So [in practice, `lsof /dev/video0`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344454/how-to-know-if-my-webcam-is-used-or-not/344503#344503) does list all processes accessing the webcam.

Comment: right. So this question was based on an application i was building to track cam usage. hence if the root user has created custom devices files accessing the cams it has to create a symbolic link to dev/video0. This makes solid sense! Thanks a lot

Comment: So you could do something like `sudo find / -type c -ls | grep 81, 2>/dev/null` to find all of the places where there might be an existing camera node and then lsof all of them.

Comment: @rotten Yes, but if you start down that path, this is still not guaranteed to find all of them. A process could be accessing a now-deleted inode referencing the same device.

Comment: So a process could `mknod` the device, connect to it, then spin off another process that deletes the node from the file system, but it still hangs on to it in the original thread.  Surely there is a way to list open files that have been deleted from the file system?  (And normally one wouldn't expect to find too many of them - especially after a reboot.)

Comment: @rotten You can traverse `/proc/*/files` or have `lsof` do it for you. One would not normally ever expect that for a device file.

Answer (score 14):

`DEVICE` `81,0` does not refer to blocks at all: together with `TYPE` `CHR` it indicates this device is a character device with major number 81 and minor number 0.

From `/proc/devices`, you can see that character device major number 81 is associated with the `video4linux` subsystem. The minor numbers are assigned by each subsystem as they see fit: in this case, the minor number is directly reflected in the device name `/dev/video0` generated by `udev`.

Classically, unix-like systems used the machine-friendly device numbers as the primary internal identifiers for devices, rather than human-friendly device names. The entire `/dev` directory tree with its device nodes is basically a big look-up table that allows the kernel's filesystem drivers to convert device names to device numbers, much like the `/etc/services` file allows you to use a port name like `ssh` or `ntp` instead of port numbers like 22 or 123, respectively.  Device nodes can also have permissions, which is also very useful for restricting inappropriate access to device drivers.

When you run `lsof` as a regular user, it may output information about your own processes only: a regular user has no business snooping on other users. Root privileges are required to see what other users' processes are doing.