# Notification when someone is accessing my Samba/CIFS share

Tags: logs, samba, cifs, notifications, smb

Is there any way I can get notification (preferably [Gnome notification](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-notifications.html.en)) when someone (privileged) is accessing my [Samba/CIFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/samba) share? If there is no such a tool, I need to implement one.

It's important for me to have such a feature, since I need to be notified when potentially big files are downloaded from my computer. BTW: I was quite surprised that [Samba](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/samba) even [does **not** have](https://moiristo.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/samba-logging-user-activity/) default access log with list of IPs and accessed files.

PS. I know that that [link I posted](https://moiristo.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/samba-logging-user-activity/) is outdated but still – it seems that Samba [doesn't log](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Client_specific_logging) who and when accessed which file (by default).

Comment: If these files are only accessed by Samba then possibly you could watch them?  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12247/linux-file-access-monitoring for details on that.

Comment: In lack of anything better, you could install Wireshark and set up a filter for viewing all access to your computer over Samba. This will list the IP + MAC addresses of people accessing the files, possibly the filenames too.

Comment: Samba logs file access with `log level` about 2, see `man smb.conf`. With a `preexec` script, you can trigger the access to the share.