# Determine the files/directories changed as a result of running a command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If I run a command in bash, is there any way to determine which files and directories were modified as a result of running that command?

For example, if i run:

```
export $MYDIR="/home/users/myuser/"
touch $MY_DIR/*
```

I would like to be able to list the files that were modified:

```
/home/users/myuser/file1
/home/users/myuser/file2
/home/users/myuser/file3
```

But not specifically for `touch`. I would like the solution to be general for *any* command.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of tools which I quite like for this kind of use case:

- [`maybe`](https://github.com/p-e-w/maybe) will run a command, but fake any modification to the file system (pretend it succeeded without performing it, and log it), then display a list of all the changes; you can then decide whether to run the command again — it’s not perfect, see [the list of issues](https://github.com/p-e-w/maybe/issues), but it’s good enough in many cases;
- [LoggedFS](https://rflament.github.io/loggedfs/) provides a logging file system overlay, which lets all changes to a file system go through but logs them, in a configurable manner (see [LoggedFS configuration file syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13794/86440) for details).

Other tools commonly used to trace file system operations include `inotifywait` and `auditd`; see [Linux file access monitoring](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12247/86440) for details.

Answer (score 1):

For a basic / simplistic solution, how about creating a file first, and then, after your operation, running a `find` to display files newer than said file ?

```
touch /tmp/myfile
( do stuff )
find ${MY_DIR} -newer /tmp/myfile
```

As @roaima points out, this only address your "which files and directories were modified as a result" requirement : it would not identify files that were removed.

Comment: You'd need a "before and after" to catch a tool that removed files

Comment: Note that it's `zsh` syntax. With `bash` (see tag in OP's question), you'd need `find "$MY_DIR"`. `find ${MY_DIR}` would only make sense in `bash` if `$MY_DIR` was meant to contain a $IFS-separated list of file patterns that you intended to expand. (:-b)