# auditd does not record actiosn by apache/php

Tags: linux-audit

I have a PHP/Apache2-based webservice and I want to audit every file-IO action it does.

I use auditd as recommended [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12247/linux-file-access-monitoring).

I set up audit.d like this

```
## enable ruleset
-e 1

## limit rate
-r 1000

## monitor
-w /var/www/html/my/path/ -p rwxa -k toplevel_my_app
```

The auditd.conf is kept as default.

Whenever I touch anything in `/var/www/html/my/path/` with whatever program it gets logged in `/var/www/html/my/path/` as expected. But when the webservice does, nothing is recorded.

When I make a simple PHP script which writes to a file in the folder, and I call it from CLI, the action gets logged. When I call the very same script via apache/localhost it doesn't get get logged.

What am I doing wrong?

I am on Debian 11 (Debian 5.10.149-2) and use PHP 8.1.13.

Comment: did you find any solution for this? I have the same problem.

Comment: @ponciste I think it had something to do with the user. Apache is another user than me on the CLI.